# C# ADO.NET: check for existing index

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have the following code and I want to show an error message if the id is not found in the table can any body help?

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
    string sql = "select * from question where id=@id;";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
    MySqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    string res = "";

    while (rd.Read())
    {
        if (rd.HasRows==true)

        {
            res = string.Format("id={0} pid={1} question={2}", rd.GetInt32(0), rd.GetInt32(1), rd.GetString(2));
            MessageBox.Show("found" + "\n" + res);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(" id not found");


    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for has rows before to start iterating the reader.

```
if (rd.HasRows==true)
{
while (rd.Read())
{
// Do something here
}
}
else
{
// Show message here
}
```